# Unable to cover code in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I have created a test class for one of my client's class. Below lines are not covering even though I created a test record for that.

Class:

```
public without sharing class ContractLogCreationController {

    /* Description: This method helps in Creating Parent ContractLog and Child Contract Logs based on the Selection
    *              from the UI i.e. It will Create a child contract Log for the current Item Setup Record and also
    *              recreate new Child Contract Logs for the selected child Contract Logs from the UI.
    */ 
        @AuraEnabled
        public static void createContractAndChildLogs(String IdsLst,String currentItemSetupId, String itemSetupLst){
            try{ 
                List<String> childLogsIds =new List<String>();
                List<String> itemSetupIds = new List<String>();
                if(string.isNotBlank(IdsLst)){
                childLogsIds = (List<String>)JSON.deserialize(IdsLst, List<String>.class);
                }
                if(String.isNotBlank(itemSetupLst)){
                    itemSetupIds = (List<String>)JSON.deserialize(itemSetupLst, List<String>.class);
                }
                system.debug('ContractLogCreationController:createContractAndChildLogs:ChildLogIds: '+childLogsIds);
                
                //BMP236 Inactive ISU/Delisting - Item Status is added in the query
                Map<Id,Item_Setup__c> itemSetupMap = new Map<Id,Item_Setup__c>([Select Id,Name,EKS_BA_Number_If_applicable__c,ELWIS_Item_Number__c,Prelisting_Item_Number_Admin_use_only__c,Item_Short_Description_Admin_use_only__c,Brand_Tier__c,Listing_Type__c,EKS_Item_Number_if_applicable__c,Buyer_Upload__c,OwnerId,Item__c,Case__c,Category_Group__c,Supplier_Setup_Form__c,Safety_Data_Sheet_s__c,Mixed_Case__c,Valid_from__c,Valid_to__c,Contract_Sub_Range__c,Contract_Number_Admin_Use_Only__c,Fixed_Quantity__c,Active_RDC__c,Brand_Name__c,Lead_Time_for_Orders__c,Supplier_Setup_Form__r.Supplier_Name__c,Supplier_Setup_Form__r.EKS_Supplier_Number_if_applicable__c,Supplier_Setup_Form__r.ELWIS_Supplier_Number_if_applicable__c,Supplier_Setup_Form__r.BIC_Key_Admin_use_only__c,Supplier_Setup_Form__r.Supplier_set_up_in_EKS_by__c,Supplier_Setup_Form__r.Supplier_set_up_Verified_by__c, Item_Status__c from Item_Setup__c Where Id IN :itemSetupIds]);
                
                Set<String> caseLst = new Set<String>();
                for(Item_Setup__c itemSetup:itemSetupMap.values()){
                    caseLst.add(itemSetup.Case__c);
                }
                List<CaseICIXProductRelationship__c> cpList = [Select Id, Case__c, ICIX_Product__c,Unit_of_Measure_a__c,Pack_Size_a__c from CaseICIXProductRelationship__c where Case__c IN :caseLst];
                
                Map<String,List<String>> caseProdMap = new Map<String,List<String>>();
                Map<String,List<CaseICIXProductRelationship__c>> caseProdRelationMap = new  Map<String,List<CaseICIXProductRelationship__c>>();
                Set<Id> prodList = new Set<Id>();
                for(CaseICIXProductRelationship__c relation: cpList){
                    if(!caseProdMap.containsKey(relation.Case__c)){
                        caseProdMap.put(relation.Case__c,new List<String>());
                        caseProdRelationMap.put(relation.Case__c,new List<CaseICIXProductRelationship__c>());
                    }
                    caseProdMap.get(relation.Case__c).add(relation.ICIX_Product__c);
                    caseProdRelationMap.get(relation.Case__c).add(relation);
                    prodList.add(relation.ICIX_Product__c);
                }
                
                System.debug('ContractLogCreationController:createContractAndChildLogs:caseProd: '+caseProdMap);
                Map<Id,Item__c> itemMap = new Map<Id,Item__c>([Select Id,Listing_Type__c,Prelisting_Item_Number__c,OwnerId,Planned_Listing_Week__c,Status__c from item__c where Id = :itemSetupMap.get(currentItemSetupId).Item__c]);
                Map<Id,ICIX_V1__ICIX_Product__c> prodMap=new Map<Id,ICIX_V1__ICIX_Product__c>([Select id,name,Item_Group_input__c,Item_Family_input__c,Case__c,Negotiating_Country__c,Brand_Name__c,
                                                                                            Buying_Director__c,Units_Per_Package_Multi_Pack__c,Individual_Product_Weight_Pack_Size__c,Unit_Of_Measure__c,Branded_or_Private_Label__c,ownerId from ICIX_V1__ICIX_Product__c  where ID in: prodList]);
                
                
                Set<Id> sid = new Set<Id>();
                for(ICIX_V1__ICIX_Product__c prod: prodMap.values()){
                    sid.add(prod.ownerId);
                }
                
                Map<Id,User> mpusers=new map<Id,user>([select id,buying_director__c from user where Id in:sid]);
                
                Contract_Log__c contract = new Contract_Log__c();
                Id conrectypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Contract_Log__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Contract Logs created from ISU').getRecordTypeId();
                contract.RecordTypeId = conrectypeId;
                contract.Supplier_Setup_Form__c =  itemSetupMap.get(currentItemSetupId).Supplier_Setup_Form__c; 
                contract.Safety_Data_Sheet_Obtained__c =  itemSetupMap.get(currentItemSetupId).Safety_Data_Sheet_s__c;
                contract.MPG_Valid_from__c =  itemSetupMap.get(currentItemSetupId).Valid_from__c;
                contract.MPG_Valid_Until__c =  itemSetupMap.get(currentItemSetupId).Valid_to__c;
                contract.Contract_Sub_Range__c = itemSetupMap.get(currentItemSetupId).Contract_Sub_Range__c;
                //contract.EKS_PA_Number__c = itemSetupMap.get(currentItemSetupId).Contract_Number_Admin_Use_Only__c;
                contract.Supplier_Setup_Form__c = itemSetupMap.get(currentItemSetupId).Supplier_Setup_Form__c;
                contract.Quantity__c = itemSetupMap.get(currentItemSetupId).Fixed_Quantity__c;
                contract.Active_RDCs_for_Case__c =  itemSetupMap.get(currentItemSetupId).Active_RDC__c;                            
                contract.Brand_Name__c = itemSetupMap.get(currentItemSetupId).Brand_Name__c;
                contract.Order_Lead_Time_Days__c = itemSetupMap.get(currentItemSetupId).Lead_Time_for_Orders__c;
                contract.Supplier_Name__c =  itemSetupMap.get(currentItemSetupId).Supplier_Setup_Form__r.Supplier_Name__c;
                contract.EKS_Supplier_Number_Manual__c = itemSetupMap.get(currentItemSetupId).Supplier_Setup_Form__r.EKS_Supplier_Number_if_applicable__c;
                contract.ELWIS_Supplier_Number_Manual__c = itemSetupMap.get(currentItemSetupId).Supplier_Setup_Form__r.ELWIS_Supplier_Number_if_applicable__c;
                contract.BIC_Key__c =  itemSetupMap.get(currentItemSetupId).Supplier_Setup_Form__r.BIC_Key_Admin_use_only__c;
                contract.Supplier_set_up_in_EKS_by__c = itemSetupMap.get(currentItemSetupId).Supplier_Setup_Form__r.Supplier_set_up_in_EKS_by__c;
                contract.Supplier_set_up_Verified_by__c = itemSetupMap.get(currentItemSetupId).Supplier_Setup_Form__r.Supplier_set_up_Verified_by__c;
                contract.Mixed_Case__c=itemSetupMap.get(currentItemSetupId).Mixed_Case__c;
                contract.ownerId = itemSetupMap.get(currentItemSetupId).OwnerId;
                contract.Buyer__c=itemSetupMap.get(currentItemSetupId).Buyer_Upload__c;
                contract.EKS_to_be_validated__c = true;
                contract.Contract_Log_Uploaded__c = false;
                contract.Document_Type__c = 'PA';
                //BMP236 Inactive ISU/Delisting - Item Status is populated on Contract Log
                contract.Status__c = itemSetupMap.get(currentItemSetupId).Item_Status__c;
    
                //Child Contract Log Creation
                List<Child_Contract_Log__c> childLogLst = new List<Child_Contract_Log__c>();
                //Creating ChildContract Logs for All the Selected Pending Changes+Current ISU from where invocation Happened
                for(String itemSetupId: itemSetupIds){
                    Child_Contract_Log__c childLog = new Child_Contract_Log__c();
                    childLog.Contract_Log__c = contract.Id;
                    childLog.MPG_Valid_from__c =itemSetupMap.get(itemSetupId).Valid_from__c;
                    childLog.MPG_Valid_Until__c = itemSetupMap.get(itemSetupId).Valid_to__c;
                    //childLog.Internal_Comments__c = contract.Contract_Comments__c;
                    childLog.Item_Setup__c = itemSetupId;
                    childLog.EKS_Item_Number__c = itemSetupMap.get(itemSetupId).EKS_Item_Number_if_applicable__c;
                    childLog.BA_Number__c = itemSetupMap.get(itemSetupId).EKS_BA_Number_If_applicable__c;
                    childLog.eLWIS_Item_Number__c = itemSetupMap.get(itemSetupId).ELWIS_Item_Number__c;
                    childLog.Prelisting_Item_Number__c = itemSetupMap.get(itemSetupId).Prelisting_Item_Number_Admin_use_only__c;
                    childLog.Item_Short_Description__c = itemSetupMap.get(itemSetupId).Item_Short_Description_Admin_use_only__c;
                    childLog.Category_Group__c   = itemSetupMap.get(itemSetupId).Category_Group__c;
                    childLog.Tier__c = itemSetupMap.get(itemSetupId).Brand_Tier__c;
                    childLog.Quantity__c = itemSetupMap.get(itemSetupId).Fixed_Quantity__c;
                    childLog.Listing_Type__c = itemSetupMap.get(itemSetupId).Listing_Type__c;
                    
                    //The below section of code is for Concatenating all the pack Sizes and Unit of Measures
                    //Values mentioned on the caseProductRelationShip record for the ItemSetup related Case field
                    //into the Child Contract Log.
                    if(!cpList.isEmpty())
                    {
                        String caseId = itemSetupMap.get(itemSetupId).Case__c;
                        Integer totalLen = 0;
                        Integer childLogPackSizeLen = 0;
                        Integer packSizelen = 0;
                        Integer childLogUomLen = 0;
                        Integer UomLen = 0;
                        childLog.Pack_Size__c = '';
                        for(CaseICIXProductRelationship__c relation: caseProdRelationMap.get(caseId)){
                            
                            childLogPackSizeLen = string.isBlank(childLog.Pack_Size__c)?0:childLog.Pack_Size__c.length();
                            packSizelen = string.isBlank(relation.Pack_Size_a__c)?0:relation.Pack_Size_a__c.length();
                            childLogUomLen = string.isBlank(childLog.Pack_Size__c)?0:childLog.Pack_Size__c.length();
                            UomLen = string.isBlank(relation.Unit_of_Measure_a__c)?0:relation.Unit_of_Measure_a__c.length();
                            totalLen = totalLen+packSizelen+UomLen;
                            if(relation.Case__c == caseId){
                                if(packSizelen !=0 && (totalLen < 255)){
                                    childLog.Pack_Size__c = childLog.Pack_Size__c+relation.Pack_Size_a__c+'-'+relation.Unit_of_Measure_a__c+'/';
                                }
                                
                            }
                            
                        }
                        childLog.Pack_Size__c = childLog.Pack_Size__c.length() > 0 ?childLog.Pack_Size__c.subString(0,childLog.Pack_Size__c.length()-1):'';
                    }
                    
                    childLogLst.add(childLog);
                }
    
                Child_Contract_Log__c clonedLog;
                for(Child_Contract_Log__c log: [Select Id,BA_Number__c,Contract_Log__c,Cloned_From__c,Category_Group__c,EKS_Item_Number__c,eLWIS_Item_Number__c,Internal_Comments__c,Item_Family__c,Item_Group__c,Item_Inactive__c,Item_Setup__c,Item_Short_Description__c,Listing_Type__c,MD_Log_Created__c,MPG_Valid_from__c,MPG_Valid_Until__c,Pack_Size__c,Prelisting_Item_Number__c,Quantity__c,Tier__c from Child_Contract_Log__c Where Id in :childLogsIds]){
                    clonedLog = log.clone();
                    clonedLog.Id = null;
                    clonedLog.Contract_Log__c = contract.Id;
                    clonedLog.Cloned_From__c = log.Id;
                    clonedLog.MD_Log_Created__c = false;
                    
                    childLogLst.add(clonedLog);
                } 
                
                insert childLogLst;
    
                List<Item_Setup__c> updatedLst = new List<Item_Setup__c>();
                Item_Setup__c itemSetupRec;
                for(String itemseupId:itemSetupIds){
                    itemSetupRec = new item_Setup__c(Id=itemseupId,Contract_Log_Created__c=true,Item_Setup_Form_Status__c='With Contracts Team');
                    updatedLst.add(itemSetupRec);
                }
                
                update updatedLst;
                
            }catch(Exception ex){
                system.debug('ContractLogCreationController:createContractAndChildLogs:Exception: '+ex.getMessage());
                throw New AuraHandledException(ex.getMessage());
            }
    }
    
}
```

---

Test Class:

```
@isTest
public class ContractLogCreationController_Test {

    public static List<User> userList;
    public static List<Item__c> itemlist{get;set;}
    public static List<Case__c> caseList{get;set;}
    public static List<ICIX_V1__ICIX_Product__c> productList;
    public static List<CaseICIXProductRelationship__c> caseProRelation;  
    public static List<ItemCaseRelationship__c> itemCaseRelationList;
    public static Li st<Account> supList;
    public static List<Item_Setup__c> itemSetupList;
    public static List<Supplier_Setup_Form__c> supplierSetupList;

    public static void init(){
    ******created a user
    }

    public static testMethod void test1(){
        init();
        itemlist =new List<Item__c>();
        ***** ****
        Created Item__c , Case__c, Case Product Relationship, Item steup records
    ************
        //Create Item Setup Form
        itemSetupList = new List<Item_Setup__c>();
        String recordId;
        List<string> isid= new List<string>(); 
        Item_Setup__c itm_setup = ICIXTestdatafactory.CreateItemSetUp(); 
        itm_setup.Name = '4444UATLIDLItemSetup1';
        itm_setup.Contract_Log_Created__c=true;
        itm_setup.Buying_Price__c = 'testsetup';
        itm_setup.Item__c = itemlist[0].Id;
        itm_setup.Case__c = caseList[0].Id;
        itm_setup.Distributor_Name__c = 'testsetup';
        itm_setup.Valid_From_Date_Approximate__c = 'Yes';
        itm_setup.Valid_to__c = Date.today();
        itm_setup.Buyer_Comments2__c = 'Testing Comments';
        itm_setup.Item_Setup_Form_Status__c='With Contracts Team';
        itm_setup.Valid_from__c = Date.today();
        itm_setup.Selected_Supplier__c = supList[0].id;
        itm_setup.Brand_Name__c = 'testname';
        itm_setup.Fixed_Quantity__c = '123';
        itm_setup.Processed__c = true;
        itm_setup.BuyingPrice_ALL__c = 10.25;
        itm_setup.BuyingPrice_FRG__c = 200.00;
        itm_setup.Contract_Sub_Range__c= null;
        itm_setup.Supplier_Setup_Form__c=supplierSetupList[0].Id;
        itm_setup.ParentId__c = null;
        itm_setup.EKS_Item_Number_if_applicable__c='9998111';
        //itm_setup.EKS_BA_Number_If_applicable__c='9998111';
        itm_setup.ELWIS_Item_Number__c='999811';
        itm_setup.Prelisting_Item_Number_Admin_use_only__c='99811';
        itm_setup.Item_Short_Description_Admin_use_only__c='ItemTest Description44';
        itm_setup.Category_Group__c='90.2';
        itm_setup.Brand_Tier__c='Private Label';
        itm_setup.Listing_Type__c='Core Range';
        itm_setup.Lead_Time_for_Orders__c='2';
        
        Item_Setup__c itm_setup2 = ICIXTestdatafactory.CreateItemSetUp(); 
        itm_setup2.Name = '4444UATLIDLItemSetup1_v1';
        itm_setup2.Buying_Price__c = 'testsetup';
        itm_setup2.Item_Setup_Form_Status__c='With Contracts Team';
        itm_setup.Contract_Log_Created__c=False;
        itm_setup2.Item__c = itm_setup.Item__c;
        itm_setup2.Case__c = itm_setup.Case__c;
        itm_setup2.Supplier_Setup_Form__c=supplierSetupList[0].Id;
        itm_setup2.Contract_Sub_Range__c= null;
        itm_setup2.Distributor_Name__c = 'testsetup';
        itm_setup2.Valid_From_Date_Approximate__c = 'Yes';
        itm_setup2.Valid_to__c = Date.today();
        itm_setup2.Buyer_Comments2__c = 'Testing Comments';
        itm_setup2.Valid_from__c = Date.today();
        itm_setup2.Selected_Supplier__c = supList[0].id;
        itm_setup2.Brand_Name__c = 'testname';
        itm_setup2.Fixed_Quantity__c = '123';
        itm_setup2.Processed__c = true;
        itm_setup2.BuyingPrice_ALL__c = 10.25;
        itm_setup2.BuyingPrice_FRG__c = 200.00;
        itm_setup2.ParentId__c=itm_setup.Id;
        
        itm_setup2.EKS_Item_Number_if_applicable__c='9998111';
    // itm_setup2.EKS_BA_Number_If_applicable__c='9998111';
        itm_setup2.ELWIS_Item_Number__c='999811';
        itm_setup2.Prelisting_Item_Number_Admin_use_only__c='99811';
        itm_setup2.Item_Short_Description_Admin_use_only__c='ItemTest Description44';
        itm_setup2.Category_Group__c='90.2';
        itm_setup2.Brand_Tier__c='Private Label';
        itm_setup2.Listing_Type__c='Core Range';
        itm_setup2.Lead_Time_for_Orders__c='2';
        itemsetuplist.add(itm_setup);
        itemsetuplist.add(itm_setup2);
        insert itemsetuplist;
        isid.add(itm_setup.Id);
        isid.add(itm_setup2.Id);
        recordId=itm_setup2.Id;
        
        //create Contract Log
        List<Contract_Log__c> contractlist = new List<Contract_Log__c>();
        Contract_Log__c contract = new Contract_Log__c();
            Id conrectypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Contract_Log__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Contract Logs created from ISU').getRecordTypeId();
            contract.RecordTypeId = conrectypeId;
            contract.Supplier_Setup_Form__c =  itemSetupList[0].Supplier_Setup_Form__c; 
            contract.Safety_Data_Sheet_Obtained__c = itemSetupList[0].Safety_Data_Sheet_s__c;
            contract.MPG_Valid_from__c =  itemSetupList[0].Valid_from__c;
            contract.MPG_Valid_Until__c =  itemSetupList[0].Valid_to__c;
            contract.Contract_Sub_Range__c = itemSetupList[0].Contract_Sub_Range__c;
            //contract.EKS_PA_Number__c = itemSetupMap.get(currentItemSetupId).Contract_Number_Admin_Use_Only__c;
            contract.Supplier_Setup_Form__c = itemSetupList[0].Supplier_Setup_Form__c;
            contract.Quantity__c = itemSetupList[0].Fixed_Quantity__c;
            contract.Active_RDCs_for_Case__c =  itemSetupList[0].Active_RDC__c;                            
            contract.Brand_Name__c = itemSetupList[0].Brand_Name__c;
            contract.Order_Lead_Time_Days__c = itemSetupList[0].Lead_Time_for_Orders__c;
            contract.Supplier_Name__c =  itemSetupList[0].Supplier_Setup_Form__r.Supplier_Name__c;
            contract.EKS_Supplier_Number_Manual__c =itemSetupList[0].Supplier_Setup_Form__r.EKS_Supplier_Number_if_applicable__c;
            contract.ELWIS_Supplier_Number_Manual__c = itemSetupList[0].Supplier_Setup_Form__r.ELWIS_Supplier_Number_if_applicable__c;
            contract.BIC_Key__c =  itemSetupList[0].Supplier_Setup_Form__r.BIC_Key_Admin_use_only__c;
            contract.Supplier_set_up_in_EKS_by__c = itemSetupList[0].Supplier_Setup_Form__r.Supplier_set_up_in_EKS_by__c;
            contract.Supplier_set_up_Verified_by__c = itemSetupList[0].Supplier_Setup_Form__r.Supplier_set_up_Verified_by__c;
            contract.Mixed_Case__c=itemSetupList[0].Mixed_Case__c;
            
            contract.Buyer__c=itemSetupList[0].Buyer_Upload__c;
            contract.EKS_to_be_validated__c = true;
            contract.Contract_Log_Uploaded__c = false;
            contract.Document_Type__c = 'PA';
            contractlist.add(contract);
            insert contractlist;
            
        
        //create child contract log
            String itemSetupId;
            isid.add(itemSetupId);
            List<Child_Contract_Log__c> childLogLst = new List<Child_Contract_Log__c>();
            Child_Contract_Log__c childLog=new Child_Contract_Log__c();
            childLog.Contract_Log__c = contract.Id;
            childLog.MPG_Valid_from__c=itemSetupList[1].Valid_from__c;
            childLog.MPG_Valid_Until__c = itemSetupList[1].Valid_to__c;
        // childLog.Internal_Comments__c = contract.Contract_Comments__c;
            childLog.Item_Setup__c = itemSetupList[1].Id;
            childLog.Item_Family__c='90.2';
            childLog.EKS_Item_Number__c = itemSetupList[1].EKS_Item_Number_if_applicable__c;
            childLog.BA_Number__c = itemSetupList[1].EKS_BA_Number_If_applicable__c;
            childLog.eLWIS_Item_Number__c = itemSetupList[1].ELWIS_Item_Number__c;
            childLog.Prelisting_Item_Number__c =itemSetupList[1].Prelisting_Item_Number_Admin_use_only__c;
            childLog.Item_Short_Description__c = itemSetupList[1].Item_Short_Description_Admin_use_only__c;
            childLog.Category_Group__c   =itemSetupList[1] .Category_Group__c;
            childLog.Tier__c = itemSetupList[1].Brand_Tier__c;
            childLog.Quantity__c =itemSetupList[1].Fixed_Quantity__c;
            childLog.Listing_Type__c =itemSetupList[1] .Listing_Type__c;
            childLog.Item_Group__c='90';
            childLog.Item_Inactive__c=False;
            childLog.MD_Log_Created__c=False;
            childLog.Cloned_From__c=null;
            
            Child_Contract_Log__c childLog2=childLog.clone();
            childLog2.Contract_Log__c = contract.Id;
            childLog2.MPG_Valid_from__c=itemSetupList[0].Valid_from__c;
            childLog2.MPG_Valid_Until__c = itemSetupList[0].Valid_to__c;
            childLog2.Internal_Comments__c = contract.Contract_Comments__c;
            childLog2.Item_Setup__c = itemSetupList[0].Id;
            childLog2.Item_Family__c='90.2';
            childLog2.Item_Group__c='90';
            childLog2.EKS_Item_Number__c = itemSetupList[0].EKS_Item_Number_if_applicable__c;
            childLog2.BA_Number__c = itemSetupList[0].EKS_BA_Number_If_applicable__c;
            childLog2.eLWIS_Item_Number__c = itemSetupList[0].ELWIS_Item_Number__c;
            childLog2.Prelisting_Item_Number__c =itemSetupList[0].Prelisting_Item_Number_Admin_use_only__c;
            childLog2.Item_Short_Description__c = itemSetupList[0].Item_Short_Description_Admin_use_only__c;
            childLog2.Category_Group__c   =itemSetupList[0] .Category_Group__c;
            childLog2.Tier__c = itemSetupList[0].Brand_Tier__c;
            childLog2.Quantity__c =itemSetupList[0].Fixed_Quantity__c;
            childLog2.Listing_Type__c =itemSetupList[0] .Listing_Type__c;
            childLog2.Cloned_From__c=childLog.Id;
            childLog2.Item_Inactive__c=False;
            childLog2.MD_Log_Created__c=False;
            childLogLst.add(childLog);
            childLogLst.add(childLog2);
        
        // insert childLogLst;
            List<string> childLogsIds=new List<Id>();
            childLogsIds.add(childLog.Id);
            childLogsIds.add(childLog2.Id);
            Child_Contract_Log__c clonedLog;
            for(Child_Contract_Log__c log: [Select Id,BA_Number__c,Contract_Log__c,Cloned_From__c,Category_Group__c,EKS_Item_Number__c,eLWIS_Item_Number__c,Internal_Comments__c,Item_Family__c,Item_Group__c,Item_Inactive__c,Item_Setup__c,Item_Short_Description__c,Listing_Type__c,MD_Log_Created__c,MPG_Valid_from__c,MPG_Valid_Until__c,Pack_Size__c,Prelisting_Item_Number__c,Quantity__c,Tier__c from Child_Contract_Log__c Where Id in :childLogsIds]){

                clonedLog = log.clone();
                
                clonedLog.Contract_Log__c = contract.Id;
                clonedLog.Cloned_From__c = log.Id;
                clonedLog.MD_Log_Created__c = false;
                
                childLogLst.add(clonedLog);
            }
            
            insert childLogLst;
            //childLogsIds.add(clonedLog.Id);
        
            List<Item_Setup__c> updatedLst = new List<Item_Setup__c>();
            Item_Setup__c is;
            for(String itemseupId:isid){
                is = new item_Setup__c(Id=itemseupId,Contract_Log_Created__c=true,Item_Setup_Form_Status__c='With Contracts Team');
                updatedLst.add(is);
            }
            
            upsert updatedLst;
            
        
            //current itemSetup is Version record if ParentId is Available
        if(string.isNotBlank(itm_setup2.ParentId__c)){
            //BMP236 Inactive ISU/Delisting - Item_Status__c and Item_Setup_Status__c field is added
            wrapper.contractLst = [Select Id,Name,EKS_Supplier_Number_Formula__c,
            ELWIS_Supplier_Number_Formula__c,Listing_Type__c,Item_short_Description_Formula__c,
            MPG_Valid_from__c,MPG_Valid_Until__c,Document_Type__c,EKS_PA_Number__c,Status__c,
            Item_Inactive__c,Item_Setup_Status__c,(Select Id,Name,Item_Setup__c,Item_Setup__r.Name,
            Item_Setup__r.Item_Short_Description_Admin_use_only__c,EKS_Item_Number__c,
            eLWIS_Item_Number__c,Category_Group__c,Item_Status__c from Child_Contract_Logs__r) 
            from Contract_Log__c Where Supplier_Setup_Form__c = :itm_setup2.Supplier_Setup_Form__c 
            AND Contract_Sub_Range__c = :itm_setup2.Contract_Sub_Range__c];
            }
            
        Item_Setup__c itemSetupRec1 = [Select Id,Name,Contract_Sub_Range__c,parentId__c,Supplier_Setup_Form__c,Contract_Log_Created__c from Item_Setup__c WHERE Name='4444UATLIDLItemSetup1_v1' LIMIT 1];        
        Contract_Sub_Range__c range = [Select Id,Name from Contract_Sub_Range__c LIMIT 1];
    

        List<String> itemSetupids = new List<String>{string.valueOf(itemSetupRec1.Id)};
        
        try{
        
        ContractLogCreationController.createContractAndChildLogs(childLogsIds[0],itemSetupRec1.Id,JSON.serialize(itemSetupids));
        }catch(Exception ex){
        
            system.assertEquals('Script-thrown exception', ex.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

I have created a Child Contract Log but from "creation of Child Contract Log" code to end of the class is not covering in test class. Catch block is covering. Can anyone please help me on this if I missed something?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @arut Thanks for your response. I have gone through the one which you suggested. But it is not helping in  my case.

Comment: If your catch block is executing, that means your log creation code is throwing an exception.  Please [edit] your post to include the stack trace and any other errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is not being covered because you threw an exception. Any code that wasn't executed prior to the exception being thrown doesn't get coverage - that's how code coverage works.

Your test for the thrown exception is not very precise. It simply checks that *some* exception was caught and then re-thrown as an `AuraHandledException`. I'm not sure what exception codepath you were trying to test, but it's possible that your test is throwing an exception for a different reason and therefore stopping execution before you expected it to.

Looking at the actual exception message and comparing it with your expectations could help identify the actual underlying problem. Based on your limited description, I would suspect your `insert` DML as throwing an unexpected exception.

Comment: Can you suggest me that how can I handle this Exception? I have no idea on that

Comment: @SanthiyaDurai As noted above, I have no real idea what is going on in your code. I am offering a theory that you will need to do some work with your logs and/or code changes to validate.